# how to fix "Unable to import 'faker' pylint(import-error)" in VSCode running a populate file in django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, pylint, faker

I want to run a populating script in django but i got pylint error before running in terminal.

1- Unable to `import 'faker'pylint(import-error)`

2- `Class 'Topic' has no 'objects' memberpylint(no-member)`

that is the same for webpage and accessrecord...

I dont know what the problem is, when i run it in terminal with command "`python populate_first_app.py"` i get this errors:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting
>   INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either
>   define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call
>   settings.configure() before accessing settings.

**Part of my code** :

```
import os
import django

from first_app.models import Topic, Webpage, AccessRecord
from faker import Faker
import random
from first_project import settings

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'first_project.settings')

django.setup()


fakegen = Faker()
topics = ['Search', 'Social', 'Marketplace', 'News', 'Games']


def add_topic():
    t = Topic.objects.get_or_create(top_name=random.choice(topics))[0]
    t.save()
    return t


 def populate(N=5):
    '''
    Create N Entries of Dates Accessed
    '''

    for entry in range(N):

        # Get Topic for Entry
        top = add_topic()

        # Create Fake Data for entry
        fake_url = fakegen.url()
        fake_date = fakegen.date()
        fake_name = fakegen.company()

        # Create new Webpage Entry
        webpg = Webpage.objects.get_or_create(
            topic=top, url=fake_url, name=fake_name)[0]
```

...

Answer (score 0):

Add this line of code to your settings.json file for python in vscode..and it will work.

```
"python.linting.pylintArgs": [
        "--load-plugins=pylint_django"
   ]
```